# Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener not being called when spinner in ListView Header

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner

If I put spinner in my `ListView` main file, `setOnItemSelectedListener` is called like normal.

Just like title says, if I put the spinner into my `ListView` **header**, it is not.  Here is config:

```
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setDivider(null);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.mastercat_header, listView, false);

        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        sort = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        strings = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.sorting_cats);
        sAdapter = new SpinnerSortAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings);
        sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sort.setAdapter(sAdapter);
        sort.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener()); // Not working properly. 




 public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

    if (pos == 0) {

        //stuff
    }

    if (pos == 1) {
        // stuff
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

}

Additional info:  This listview is part of slider menu in jfeinstien's `SlidingMenu` library.  It is also a `Fragment`.

Did I find a bug or is my code wrong?

Comment: Possibly the same problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923310/android-spinner-onitemselected-setonitemselectedlistener-not-triggering