# Android Click and spinner selected listener

Tags: android, listener, handlers

I'm trying to implement spinner listener in button click handlers...
Can we Implement Android spinner item selected listener in button click handler?

Comment: did you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923310/android-spinner-onitemselected-setonitemselectedlistener-not-triggering

Comment: See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener).

Answer (score 4):

On your button click event use the following code to trigger the spinner.
Android Click and spinner selected listener:
1.spinner.performClick(); to open a spinner.
2.spinner.setSelectedItem(index);
First one will perform a normal click event just like we clik on a spinner. And the second one will set the specified index as selected spinner item, which trigger spinner item selected listener.