# How show Button only if Spinner is selected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Button:

```
<Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:onClick="test"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and I have 3 Spinners and I would that when ALL 3 spinners have a value selected, button visibility change in Visible.

Are there a differents ways for do this without check any time that I select spinner if 3 values is selected?
Are there "watcher" for this type of operation?

**EDIT**

This is my function that in this moment I call at `onItemSelected` in spinners:

```
public void checkSpinner(){
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        assert spinner1 != null;
        int position1= spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        assert spinner2 != null;
        int position2=spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        assert spinner3 != null;

        int position3=spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        if((position1>0) && (position2>0)&&(position3>0))
        {

            button .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            button .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have make a function that launch every time select one spinner, and I ask if are there other ways, or a way like "one watch" that check if values are selected

Comment: Can you update your question with the code?

Comment: The method seems to be okay except few performance issues. When do you call this `checkSpinner()`?

Comment: I call this method in 
`onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                checkSpinner();
}` 
In all 3 spinner

Comment: I guess you're facing the same issue as this. Check if any of the solutions there work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923310/android-spinner-onitemselected-setonitemselectedlistener-not-triggering

Comment: I'm Looking, but this thread talk about not trigger event, but my event is triggered, maybe I explained bad, sorry for my English. 
I ask if there is a method for not having throw any time onItemSelected in 3 different spinner? A sort of watcher for all spinners in activity?
I mean like $watch on angularjs for web development.

Comment: If I understand it clearly, you need some sort of callback which only fires when selection has been made in all 3 Spinners. If this is the case, it might be possible through RxJava. You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4) as a tutorial. If you're familiar with RxJava then just check out the `combineLatest` thing in [this tutorial](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples), I recall that the video talked about it. If you come up with a way what you want, post it as answer (and mark it) + update your question as well. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of the selecteditem from all the 3 spinners and **then compare the values with your desired values**,if they are equal then show the button.

```
String text1=spinner1.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

String text2=spinner2.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

String text3=spinner3.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

if(text1.equals("your desired value") && text2.equals("your desired value") && text3.equals("your desired value"))
{
  button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but this I have to launch any time I select one spinner right?